# Question is a duplicate of a question on another Stack Exchange website

Tags: discussion, support

If a question is a duplicate of another on a *different* Stack Exchange website such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/), then would I link it in the comments or paste the solution as an answer so it can be stored on AU for other possible duplicates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can paste the answer here but you should link the profile of the original poster and explicitly state where you got it from.

Example:

This answer was posted first by [Owen Hines](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/602680/owen-hines) on [unix&linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) please consider voting there if this helped you.

> This is the body as a quote

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation and format!

Comment: Even nicer @OwenHines you can do what Mark Kirby did the other day in the same situation and make the post a community wiki :)

Comment: @Zanna I think, as high rep users, if we just copy an answer from somewhere like Unix and don't add anything to it, we should really make it a wiki. We make plenty of rep and it is good to sent votes to the OP, as they did write it. For low rep users, it should be OK for them to get a bit of rep for finding the information.

Comment: that's another nice thought :)